# Slow performance of Postgresql script with foreign server

Tags: postgresql, performance, foreign-data-wrapper

As a former SQL Server developer, I am curious, why that kind of script can be extremely slow in Postgresql?

I have some tables on local database in public schema, and I configured a foreign server with postgres-fdw, and foreign tables are mapped in linked schema locally, and the script looks like below:

```sql
INSERT INTO linked.table_1 (column_1, column_2) SELECT column_1, column_2 FROM public.table_1;
INSERT INTO linked.table_2 (column_1, column_2) SELECT column_1, column_2 FROM public.table_2;
INSERT INTO linked.table_3 (column_1, column_2) SELECT column_1, column_2 FROM public.table_3;
-- more tables like this...
INSERT INTO linked.table_50 (column_1, column_2) SELECT column_1, column_2 FROM public.table_50;
```

Tables are small (tens, hundreds or thousands of records), so it should be pretty fast, but it takes long minutes. Why?

Comment: How far away is your foreign server? Long network round-trip time for fdw can cause what you are seeing. Do queries to the local tables run quickly?

Comment: Not enough information. Need 1) Postgres versions on both ends 2) Per previous comment, network distance 3) The `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` result for the query.  4) Hardware specifications for both machines. Add answers as update to question.

Comment: Are you using v14 and did you set `batch_size` to a largish value on the foreign server?  That can make a huge difference.

Comment: @MosheKatz, I am using a corporate VPN, servers are located in a small area, less than 50 km.

Comment: @jjanes, thank you for the tip, I am working on a server v14.1 linked to a foreign server v12.9.